# phpMyAdmin Error After Upgrade to 3.5.8.1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a newbie in MySQL. I use it only for PHP.

I tried to upgrade myphpadmin 3.5.8.1. After doing that, I couldn't access my database and got the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE db_name = 'happy2'  AND table_name = 'foto'  ORDER BY version DESC' at line 1

My Other ALL DB have error like that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Ok.. Can you post complete MySQl query? You can refer a similar question on: http://goo.gl/7ch9L

Comment: @user2045846 this my query: SELECT tracking_active FROM.WHERE db_name = 'happy2'
AND table_name = 'listingfee'
ORDER BY version DESC , Its no mistake with my OLD phpmyadmin, but after upgrade, the Error show after I Click on any table

Comment: could you please check this:  FROM.WHERE in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, when downgrading phpMyAdmin. When I deleted my cookies, the problem went away.